# ORA-01722: invalid number when removing one line

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my working code:

```
select conitem.name as LANG, 
(select rating_short_descr 
 from hrt_rating_levels_tl 
 where rating_level_id = items.rating_level_id1 and language = 'US') AS READING,
(select rating_short_descr 
 from hrt_rating_levels_tl 
 where rating_level_id = items.rating_level_id2 and language = 'US') AS SPEAKING,
(select rating_short_descr 
 from hrt_rating_levels_tl 
 where rating_level_id = items.rating_level_id3 and language = 'US') AS WRITING,
(select rating_short_descr 
 from hrt_rating_levels_tl 
 where rating_level_id = items.item_text30_7 and language = 'US') AS SIGN_LANGUAGE
from hrt_profile_items items 
 inner join hrt_content_types_tl types 
  on items.content_type_id = types.content_type_id 
 inner join hrt_profiles_b prof 
  on items.profile_id = prof.profile_id 
 inner join per_all_people_f pers  
  on pers.person_id = prof.person_id 
  and trunc(sysdate) between pers.effective_start_date and pers.effective_end_date
 left outer join hrt_content_items_tl conitem 
  on items.content_item_id = conitem.content_item_id 
  and types.language = conitem.language
where 
types.content_type_name ='Languages'
and items.date_to IS NULL
and pers.person_number = :person_number -- FINE HERE
order by types.content_type_name, pers.person_number, items.profile_item_id
```

However if I remove the commented line I get (`--FINE HERE`)

```
oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.servlet.data.DataException: oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

I don't get it - how is this even happening? It's mind boggling

UPDATED CODE STILL NOT WORKING

```
select conitem.name as LANG, 
(select rating_short_descr 
 from hrt_rating_levels_tl 
 where rating_level_id = items.rating_level_id1 and language = 'US') AS READING,
(select rating_short_descr 
 from hrt_rating_levels_tl 
 where rating_level_id = items.rating_level_id2 and language = 'US') AS SPEAKING,
(select rating_short_descr 
 from hrt_rating_levels_tl 
 where rating_level_id = items.rating_level_id3 and language = 'US') AS WRITING,
(select rating_short_descr 
 from hrt_rating_levels_tl 
 where rating_level_id = items.item_text30_7 and language = 'US') AS SIGN_LANGUAGE
from hrt_profile_items items 
 inner join hrt_content_types_tl types 
  on items.content_type_id = types.content_type_id 
 inner join hrt_profiles_b prof 
  on to_char(items.profile_id) = to_char(prof.profile_id )
 inner join per_all_people_f pers  
  on to_char(pers.person_id) = to_char(prof.person_id )
  --and trunc(sysdate) between pers.effective_start_date and pers.effective_end_date
 left outer join hrt_content_items_tl conitem 
  on items.content_item_id = conitem.content_item_id 
  and types.language = conitem.language
where 
types.content_type_name ='Languages'
and items.date_to IS NULL
order by types.content_type_name, pers.person_number, items.profile_item_id
```

Comment: `However if I remove the commented line` I can't see any commented line in your code

Comment: -- FINE HERE - I mention it in the main body

Comment: @pee2pee `and pers.person_number = :person_number` what value are you passing for the bind variable `person_number`? Also, how are you executing the SQL?

Comment: It can be text or number - using it in a data model in OTBI. The SQL is fine but when executing I can that error. The SQL shown runs perfectly but I want to remove the param. When I do, that's when it breaks

Answer (score 1):

Check all column types in the tables of all comparisons in your query. There must be a mismatch between a character column and a number column. This can also happen in your subqueries.

Without knowing your data model, this comparison: `rating_level_id = items.item_text30_7` sounds shady to me as it looks like you are comparing an id (typically NUMBER) against a text field (typically VARCHAR2). If any of the values in column `item_text30_7` can not be implicitly cast to a number then that would lead to this error.

Answer (score 0):

You may get ORA-1722 when comparing a character data type and a number when Oracle cannot convert automatically the character data to number data type.

Check you join conditions: is there any mix of character data and numeric data ?

Comment: Can I put to_char() on the joins to fix? I did try but didn't work so was just wondering if that was a viable solution

Comment: @pee2pee instead of randomly trying to cast columns, check what the *actual* type of all columns (involved in comparisons) is. *Then* you may cast exactly where needed

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, using the below filter predicate your SQL works fine:

```
and pers.person_number = :person_number -- FINE HERE
```

However, it's when you remove this filter you get: **ORA-01722: invalid number**

So, looking at your SQL, this is where the data type mismatch could be happening:

```
inner join per_all_people_f pers  
  on pers.person_id = prof.person_id
  and trunc(sysdate) between pers.effective_start_date and pers.effective_end_date
```

Compare the data between:

1. `pers.person_id` and `prof.person_id`.
2. and `trunc(sysdate)` between `pers.effective_start_date` and `pers.effective_end_date`

The error could also be coming from date calculation as well.

Comment: I have tried to_char(pers.person_id) = to_char(prof.person_id) but this doesn't work either

Comment: See my update, there is a date condition as well. And the error could come from date calculation as well.

Comment: Check all the data types of all the columns involved in either joins or equality operators. If data is not too huge, I would quickly debug it in a PL/SQL loop and catch the value which is causing the error.